# Visual Studio Xamarin connect iPhone, can't find "Remote Login"

Tags: iphone, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am trying to deploy app from Visual Studio to iPhone for testing. After I press F5 and targetting "iPhone", the system pop up a windows saying that

"Please enable Remote Login"

Search it from [Sharing] > System Preference

But, I can't find this option in iphone.

Any clues? Hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Remote Login` in a feature on your Mac, not your phone.  VS will deploy to your iPhone via the Mac build server.

Comment: Can I install a Virtual Mac in my windows 10?

Comment: Running OS X on non-Apple hardware is a violation of Apple's license terms

Comment: For more context:

`you are granted a limited, nonexclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a single Apple branded computer at any one time.`

and

`The grants set forth in this License do not permit you to, and you agree
not to, install, use or run the Apple Software on any non-Apple-branded computer, or to enable
others to do so.` - http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1011.pdf